# Keep ionic 4 alive even if page was changed

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic 4 and firebase as my database. I have image upload functionality and it's working fine. What I want to do is upload it in background. Even if I change page the upload will still continue.

Comment: Add a new page realated to uploads, and make a service for uploads, when the user click to upload,it will be added in a task in service and could view it from upload page.

Comment: Welcome mate <3.